# Horizontal cell gradient inside vertical gredient

Tags: vba, excel, cell, gradient

I've menaged to achieve result "A" as shown on attached picture. **I want to achieve result "B"**. So I need insert somehow vertical gradient inside horizontal gradient.
[image: result A and B]

Result "A" is achived this way:

```
With MyRange.Interior
    .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
    .Gradient.Degree = 0
    .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
End With

With MyRange.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
    .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

With MyRange.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(factor1 - 0.0000001)
    .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

With MyRange.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(factor1)
    .Color = statecolor
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

With MyRange.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(factor2)
    .Color = statecolor
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

With MyRange.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(factor2 + 0.0000001)
    .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Comment: it is called a sparkline. available since excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

You are already using `.Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient` in 0° direction. Obviously, cell or range can have applied only one gradient at once: it has only one `Interior` with one `Pattern`. So you cannot add 90° one as a *second* gradient. Perhaps you can consider different effect, e.g. diagonal orientation and thus making a yellow corner.

Perhaps you can achieve custom effect by using one of techniques for adding cell background image ([few examples](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/707313-background-image-in-single-or-multiple-cells.html)), but I am not sure how effective and maintainable it would be.